# How to stop a service only when the entire app is paused and closed and not use a base activity

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I am looking for a solution to kill a service only when my app itself is paused or closed.  Please note, I am not referring to one activity, I am looking for when any activity within the app is in the foreground while it is paused or killed.   I have a lot of activities, so I don't want to extend them all from a BaseActivity.  Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: check this https://github.com/friendlyrobotnyc/TinyDancer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/codemonkeylabs/fpslibrary/Foreground.java

Comment: This makes no sense. Please explain what your `Service` is doing and why you need such strange behaviour.

Comment: @DavidWasser - Strange behavior?  I don't think you have much experience with Android if you think an activity controlling the lifecycle of a service is strange behavior.

Comment: @DavidWasser - what part of this question is strange ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Apps are not "paused" or "closed".  You cannot "kill" a `Service`. You have at your disposal `startService()`, `bindService()`, `stopService()`. You can send data to your `Service` in an `Intent`.  Please use clearer language. What exactly is it that you want to do?

Comment: @SofiaClover my 43.000 reputation points are all from answering Android questions, so you must be right: I don't have much experience with Android.

Answer (score 0):

Set an uncaught exception handler for your main thread in `onCreate` of your `Application`

```
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                // Kill your service here
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(10);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is pausing/closing an app trigger an uncaught exception ?  Please explain why you think the Thread exception occurs by doing so?

Comment: There is no "close" for Android apps!! So I expect it would be a crash.

Answer (score 0):

> [START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY[START_STICKY])
>
> the system will try to re-create your service after our App/service is
>   killed
>
> [START_NOT_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY%20[START_NOT_STICKY])
>
> the system will not try to re-create your service after our App/service is killed

```
 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       // We want to stop this service, when our Application is  
       // not running (foreground/background), so return non-sticky.
       return START_NOT_STICKY;
 }
```

Hope this would help you!

Comment: I am not worried about restarting the service.  As stated, I need to kill the service when any activity in my app is paused or closed.

Comment: If you start your service with **START_NOT_STICKY** flag; System will take care of killing your service when your Application is not active in foreground/background.

Comment: The definition of both explicitly states they are invoked only when the "service's process is killed".  If the app goes onPause, the process is not killed.